# Gradle sync failed: Could not GET https://jcenter.bintray.com

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I created a Kotlin application according to JetBrains's tutorial in the following link. But I encountered the build failed error. what is wrong?

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-your-first-kotlin-app.html?section=Gradle%20Groovy

These are my screenshots:

[image]

[image: Tese are my screenshots:]

and the entire build log is:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 1 s 83 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'hello'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-api:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-api:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-api:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-api:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-model:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-model:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-model/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-model-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-model/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-model-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-tooling-core:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-tooling-core:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-tooling-core/1.7.21/kotlin-tooling-core-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-tooling-core/1.7.21/kotlin-tooling-core-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea-proto:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea-proto:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea-proto/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea-proto-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea-proto/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-idea-proto-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-util-klib:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-util-klib:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-util-klib/1.7.21/kotlin-util-klib-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-util-klib/1.7.21/kotlin-util-klib-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-klib-commonizer-api:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-klib-commonizer-api:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-klib-commonizer-api/1.7.21/kotlin-klib-commonizer-api-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-klib-commonizer-api/1.7.21/kotlin-klib-commonizer-api-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-project-model:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-project-model:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-project-model/1.7.21/kotlin-project-model-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-project-model/1.7.21/kotlin-project-model-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.7.21/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.7.21/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle/1.7.21/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle/1.7.21/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions/1.7.21/kotlin-android-extensions-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions/1.7.21/kotlin-android-extensions-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-runner:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-runner:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-runner/1.7.21/kotlin-compiler-runner-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-runner/1.7.21/kotlin-compiler-runner-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable/1.7.21/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable/1.7.21/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable:1.7.21.
     Required by:
         project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.21 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable:1.7.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable/1.7.21/kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable-1.7.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable/1.7.21/kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
```

Comment: This build log is not very informative. Please copy&paste the entire build output

Comment: `Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden` Turn on you VPN bro.

Comment: welcome to Gradle Errors ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your IntelliJ IDEA to the newest version and recreate a project.
You can also remove the `jcenter()` usage from your `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`.

---

**Reason:**

Your Gradle log says

```
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api/1.7.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-api-1.7.21.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

which means it was trying to download Kotlin from JCenter. However, JCenter had [stopped their service on May 1st 2021](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/).

Kotlin is also available on Maven Central. It is encouraged to use Maven Central.

Newer IntelliJ would generate projects using Maven Central by default.
For you, I guess you are using an old IntelliJ IDEA, or an old Kotlin or Gradle plugin.

---

**Why can't Gradle fallback to Maven Central?**

When you declare multiple repositories, Gradle will try them one by one. If one repository returned `404 Not Found`, Gradle attempts other repositories, which sounds good. But if Gradle receives an error from a repository, like in your case, it throws an exception complaining about that and crashes the build.

Comment: I just install IntelliJ version 2022.3.1; ```jcenter()``` does not exists in my ```build.gradle```  or ```settings.gradle``` project files. Insted ```build.gradle``` contains: ```repositories {     mavenCentral() }    ```